# How is the current format for an MTG booster draft calculated?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-drafting

I know that once all three sets in a block are out, a draft consists of one pack of each; and I know that when only the first set is out, a draft consists of three packs of that set.

What's the format when only two sets are out? Does the format change depending on which sets are large and which are small? And what happened to draft during Lorwyn–Shadowmoor?

Comment: Not always one of each when third set is out. What packs are used is determined by Wizard on a set-by-set basis. I think the "default" is 1,1,2. The base set tends to have more cards and provides a more solid base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wizards of the Coast designs sets for specific Limited environments.

The intended draft format for Lorwyn/Shadowmoor block was:

- Lorwyn draft: 3x Lorwyn
- Morningtide draft: 2x Lorwyn, 1x Morningtide
- Shadowmoor draft: 3x Shadowmoor
- Eventide draft: 2x Shadowmoor, 1x Eventide

Cards from the two halves of the set were not intended to be drafted together.

The [MTG Tournament Rules](http://www.wizards.com/wpn/Document.aspx?x=Magic_The_Gathering_Tournament_Rules) specify the officially-recommended booster mix for current sets (see Appendix D).

Comment: (Also, note that the order has changed; at the time it was Lorwyn-Lorwyn-Morningtide, but now the order would be reversed.)

Comment: As an update to demonstrate that there is no fixed rule for how drafts are constructed, Khans of Tarkir block will will have three very different draft structures. Khans-Khans-Khans to start, Fate Reforged-Khans-Khans when Fate Reforged is released, and finally Louie-Louie-Fate Reforged when the third set (codenamed "Louie") is released.